# checking port for availability before creating DatagramSocket

Tags: java, sockets

This question is about datagram socket not tcp sockets, so please review it first before thinking its duplicate Is there a way to check the port before creating a new DatagramSocket. When the port is in use for example by another instance the code below throws SocketException

```
    socket = new DatagramSocket(4446);
```

I would like to have it checked before I create the DatagramSocket object. So that if it is not available I can increment it and check again untill it becomes available and then I create the Socket ?

Answer (score 2):

No. Do not think that you can check all the circumstances that might cause something to fail and then be guaranteed that it will succeed. First, you'll never be able to reliably cover all the ways it can fail. Second, things can change after you test and before you operate. Instead, try to do it, and if you fail, handle the failure. If the socket construction throws an exception, then try a different port.

Comment: (Not at least) plus one for "*things can change after  ....*".

Comment: Sure that makes sense,,..  I will loop and catch and try limited number of times before it gives up..